# I: am trying to use STR_TO_DATE but why does this return null?

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

INSERT INTO covernote (issue_date) VALUES
(  STR_TO_DATE (  '13-May-13','%Y-%m-%d') );

Comment: Because May is not %m see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

Because May is not %m see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format - %b for abbreviated month or %M for full month name

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '13-May-13','%Y-%m-%d') | STR_TO_DATE( '13-May-13','%Y-%b-%d') | STR_TO_DATE( '13-May-13','%Y-%M-%d') |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| NULL                                 | 2013-05-13                           | 2013-05-13                           |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.106 sec)
```

It's a pity you picked may as a representative sample..

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation on date formatting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), `%m` is the code for "Month, numeric (00..12)".

You are looking for `%M`, which represents "Month name (January..December)"

Comment: i want to convert 13-May-13 to mysql date format which is Y-m-d

Comment: ok i got your point .It worked . thanks alot

Comment: Happy to help! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Or possibly %b.